# Regular expression for date shown as YYYY

Tags: python, regex, date

Can someone help me with regular expression for python which matches dates purely in format `yyyy` i.e. it should not match any dates such as `mm-dd-yyyy` / `Month dd, yyyy` / `dd Month, yyyy` etc.

Easy to find such matches where texts start with `yyyy`. But becomes increasingly difficult when it is in the middle or end of the line. **All other formats of dates have been matched. so repetitions are to be avoided.**

Ex:

1. 'Train accident in `1984` had a heavy death toll' - should match
2. 'One of the injured succumbed to injuries on `Jun 10 1984`' should not match
3. '`Sep 15, 1984` .... '- should not match

Comment: So you just need a four-digit number? `\b\d{4}\b`

Comment: is it ok to match 1984 in `Sep 15, 1984`?

Comment: Condition being the four digit number shouldnt follow month name `(Jan, or January or Sep or Sep.)` / date digits `(10, 10-)` followed by a space.

`1984` in `Sep 15, 1984` should not be matched.

`\b\d{4}\b` doesnt match anything. word endings do not work with digits. Correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: Deal with that in post-processing, regex is not invented for irregular patterns (i.e. patterns vastly different from one another such as `Jan 15, 1948` and `15th of January, 1948`). A regex pattern that would cover every conceivable case would be humongous and ludicrously inefficient.

Comment: > All other cases covered. Only 4 digit numbers remaining.

Comment: `not a digit or comma` followed by `whitespace` followed by `four digits` followed by `whitespace or punctuation or end of string`.

Comment: >wwii `not a digit or comma **or Jan|Feb|Mar|Apr....**` followed by `whitespace` followed by `four digits` followed by `whitespace or punctuation or end of string`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The "basic" regex matching just the *year* field is `\d{4}`
but it is not enough.
We must prohibit that before the year occurs:

- 3 letters (*month*) and a space,
- then 2 digits (*day*) and a space.

This can be achieved with *negative lookbehind*:

```
(?<!\w{3} \d{2} )
```

But note that:

- after the *day* field there can be an **optional** *comma* (`,`),
- but negative lookbehind does not allow quantifiers
  making the pattern non-fixed width,

so we can not put `,*` after the *day* field.

Fortunately, the case is not very complicated and we can circumvent this
limitation, using **two** negative lookbehinds, one with a comma after
the *day* field and another without.

So the whole regex can be as follows:

```
(?<!\w{3} \d{2}, )(?<!\w{3} \d{2} )\d{4}
```

If you want to disallow only actual month names at the beginning
(not any 3-letter word), replace both instances of `\w{3}` with:

```
(?:Jan|Feb|Mar|Apr|May|Jun|Jul|Aug|Sep|Oct|Nov|Dec)
```

## Edit

Another solution, "aware" also of **full** month names is:
Catch initially **two** groups:

- an optional "envelope" (non-capturing) group, composed of:

  - a word (capturing group No 1, possibly month name),
  - a space, 2 digits (day), optional comma and a space,
- then 4 digits (capturing group No 2).

To sum up:

```
(?:(\w+) \d{2},* )?(\d{4})
```

Then, in the post-processing phase you must:

- check the 1st captured group whether it contains either full or abbreviated
  name of any month,
- reject the cases where the test just before succeeded.

But if the test just mentioned failed, then capturing group No 2 contains
the *year* field you are looking for.